# Perl returing multiData from sub

Tags: perl

I am new to Perl and having some problems figuring out the best way to return multiple arrays from a sub. Here is my code for starters.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use List::Util;
use Fcntl 'O_RDONLY';
use Tie::File;
use YAML qw();

my $digitData   = 'digitData.txt';
my $alphaData = 'alphaData.txt';

my (@dataA, @dataN) = dataMod();
print Dumper(@dataA);
print Dumper(@dataN);

sub dataMod {
    my (@alphaData, @numData);
    my $fileCount = `wc -l < $alphaData`;;
    chomp $fileCount;
    my $history   = eval {YAML::LoadFile('history.yaml')} || {};

    $history->{$_} && --$history->{$_} for keys %$history;

    tie my @alphas, 'Tie::File', $alphaData, mode => O_RDONLY;
    tie my @nums, 'Tie::File', $digitData, mode => O_RDONLY;

    LINES: for (1 .. $fileCount) {
            my @alphaPool = @alphas;
            my $pair;

            while (@alphaPool) {
                    my @numberPool = @nums;
                    my $tryAlpha = splice @alphaPool, rand(@alphaPool), 1;

                    while (@numberPool) {
                            my $tryNum = splice @numberPool, rand(@numberPool), 1;

                            next if $history->{"$tryAlpha|$tryNum"};

                            @alphas = grep {$_ ne $tryAlpha} @alphas;
                            @numberPool = grep {$_ != $tryNum} @numberPool;
                            #print "$tryAlpha $tryNum\n";
                            push @alphaData, $tryAlpha;
                            push @numData, $tryNum;
                            $history->{"$tryAlpha|$tryNum"} = 5;
                            next LINES;
                    }

                    @alphas = grep {$_ ne $tryAlpha} @alphas;
            }
    }
    YAML::DumpFile('history.yaml', $history);
    return(@alphaData, @numData);
}
```

I am having trouble figuring out the best way to return the data from the subroutine.  I need to conserve or be able to print the data from these two variables: $tryAlpha $tryNum together once they are returned.

Currently it returns each value disjoined. An it appears that only one array has data?

Current output is in this format:

```
$VAR1 = cellCpe2
$VAR2 = stemClearSte
$VAR3 = OctuStemPr2
$VAR4 = 10
$VAR5 = 30
$VAR6 = 20
```

The problem is, I would like to use it in the format that is returned when inside the subroutine when the following print statement is executed within the sub: 
print "$tryAlpha $tryNum\n";

The result of this print statement, I need to be able to use the same logic for the data as in the print statement:
ie: $varForAlphaData $varForNumData

```
cellCpe2 10
stemClearSte 30
OctuStemPr2 20
```

For testing purposes I am using two files
*digitData.txt: Contains three words cellCpe2, stemClearSte, OctuStemPr2.  One per line

*alphaData.txt: Contains 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60.  One per line

Not sure what I am doing wrong at this point.

Comment: When you say `I would like to use it in the format that is returned when inside the subroutine when the following print statement is executed within the sub: print "$tryAlpha $tryNum\n";` does that mean you want it to do the same thing here.... `print Dumper(@dataA);
print Dumper(@dataN);` ????

Comment: What I need to be able to do is use two variables outside the sub and have both contain the matching data.  Same data that is returned when running print $tryAlpha $tryNum\n" inside the subroutine.

Comment: It does contain matching data; you're just not printing it out right.  See my `short answer` section.

Comment: A Perl subroutine returns a list of scalar values. It cannot return two arrays. It can, however, return references to two arrays. That's what you need to do here.

Comment: FYI, @davorg 's comment made me realize my `short answer` was incorrect so I pulled it out.  The longer answer using hashes as opposed to two arrays is still there though.

Answer (score 5):

Return references. Your two arrays flatten when used in list context.

```
return(\@alphaData, \@numData);
```

Usage:

```
my ($alpha, $num) = dataMod();
for my $item (@$alpha) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Use array references

```
return(\@alphaData, \@numData);
```

[How to return multiple arrays from subroutine?](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=559158)

Answer (score 3):

Since you want output like:

```
cellCpe2 10
stemClearSte 30
OctuStemPr2 20
```

I'm assuming that those values have some kind of relationship.  As in cellCpe2 has a value of 10, stemClearSte has a value of 30, and OctuStemPr2 has a value of 20.  In this case, you should probably be using a hash as opposed to two arrays since this will enforce the relationships in a programmatic way.  This will ensure that you keep your related data together.  Example...

```
#declare....
my $data = someFunction();

#print the data
foreach my $key (keys %$data) {

  #The reason the notation is not $data{$key}
  #is because you're NOT using a hash here, but
  # a reference to the hash from someFunction
  my $val = $data->{$key};

  print "\n$key $val";
}

#inside function
sub someFunction() {

  # declare a new hash...
  my %data = ();

  while (aCondition) {
    #do some stuff to define val
    my $varA = $val;
    while (bCondition) {
      #do some stuff to define anotherVal
      my $varB = $anotherVal;

      #save in your hash
      $data{$varA} = $varB;
    }
  }

  #return a reference to your hash
  return \%data;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for all the responses. I took your example on hashes and implemented that into my code.  Works great. Also thanks to everyone who took the time to explain/provide an answer.

Comment: @user1048209, if the answer is correct, then you should mark it correct by clicking the check mark, this gives Dave points, gives you a few points, helps future readers find the right answer, and shows that you appreciate good answers. Welcome to SO!